# How to access Bootstrap global variables?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to access variables like `@screen-sm-min`. I can't figure out how to do that in Meteor. (I've already added the `twbs:bootstrap` package).

Comment: try adding on the /lib folder a new css and override the @screen-sm-min variable it should work

Comment: Well yes, I could just define it myself after I go look up what its default value is. I'd rather just reference it properly as it's already defined.. should be. Somewhere...

Comment: did you try looking on `appname>.meteor>local>build>programs>web.browser>packages`? .meteor is a hidden file

Comment: Are you using LESS ? `twbs:bootstrap` do not provide LESS support, the atmosphere README hints at using another package : "If you need more detailed control on the files, or to use .less, see Nemo64's package." (https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap)

Comment: I did run `meteor add less` but I'm not sure if that's the right package. I'll check out the Nemo64 one.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion explains it all.

"Next, you have the official Bootstrap smart package twbs:bootstrap. This has the advantage of being always up to date and officially sanctioned. If you want stock Bootstrap, this is your best bet. However, there are a couple of disadvantages, namely, when you use this package what you get is the compiled CSS and Javascript added to your project, without the less files and without the ability to load only a subset of the Bootstrap features."

Check out emgee's comment in this thread - [What's with Bootstrap?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/whats-with-bootstrap/2855/6)